# Can one turn comments into a chat retroactively?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation, chat

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577042/exam-layout-with-geometry-and-tcolorbox) the comments keep piling up.  I wish I had started a chat earlier.  Now it doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: You could use the “flag comment” function and choose “Something else” as the reason and type something like “Please move this discussion to chat”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moderators can move all the comments to chat (and that has promptly been done in this case), but it can only be done once for each question.

Comment: Thanks, but it was the comments after the answer that needed to be converted.